# python3 library disappear after installing it

Tags: python-3.6, installation-package

I am installing a python library called requests-html (https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html). It is only available in python3.6.

I first download anaconda for python 3.6. Then download the source file for requests_html, go to the folder and using:

`sudo python3 setup.py install`

After this, if I go into python3 environment in the same terminal, I can import this library. However, if I open a new terminal or close the original terminal and open a new one, it says the library is not found. It seems I need to install the library again each time I want to use it and I can only use it in the same terminal which I used to install it.

This is really strange, can someone shed light on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You sure that in the original terminal you weren't working out of a virtual environment and so installed it into that. Then when you created a new terminal, because the virtual environment wasn't activated it wasn't found.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for the clue. I am not familiar with the virtual enviroment, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `sudo`? If you use python anaconda version, your python base environment is available without root for any action. Because you use `sudo`, you are using the system version. Also, you can install directly in pip.

Remember activate your environment (`conda activate`).

```
pip install requests-html
```